# Parsing and manipulating oddly formatted data, whilst maintaining formatting

Tags: java, parsing

I'm a pretty newbie programmer and basically I'm trying to parse and manipulate a DL_POLY config file, which has the layout

```
 CONFIG file created from Xmol file config.xmol                                 
         2         3  10000000    0.5000000000E-03
     31.309729731729      0.000000000000      0.000000000000
      0.000000000000     31.309729731729      0.000000000000
      0.000000000000      0.000000000000     31.309729731729
Ca              1
     6.421269411        -1.034199034         1.228702751    
  -1.06475894897       1.10274459622       1.31459311620    
  -6319.67959205      -10299.4183311       468.606019012
```

which sort of goes on for about 150 odd more entries of just the

```
Ca              1
     6.421269411        -1.034199034         1.228702751    
  -1.06475894897       1.10274459622       1.31459311620    
  -6319.67959205      -10299.4183311       468.606019012
```

segment, where the second row represents x, y and z coordinates, which I need to manipulate by adding a slight displacement to, and the top row, where Ca represents the atom (in this instance, calcium) and the integer is an atom counter (this is the first atom, I have a system of about 75 CaCO3).

Now I've written some java code which reads in the string, sticks it in an arrayList and tokenises it and from there I'm pretty sure how to add the displacement only maintaining this weird formatting complicates it all. Obviously I'm aiming for as general a solution as I can get here, so I can reuse this, whilst I'm sure I could force it into the correct format, it means I can only ever use it for that file.

So, my questions are, how can I manipulate values in a file in java, keeping the format 100% intact? And within this system, how can I tell it to add the displacement on only the second row of each segment?

It's a bit complicated (or maybe not, I really don't know) but I would really appreciate some help.

So, I've got something like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class testArrayReader {
static ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();



public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr = null;
    String[][] twodim = null;
    System.out.println("Array List initialised!");

        try{
            FileReader input = new FileReader(urlfortextfile);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input);
            System.out.println("Scanned!");
            String line;
            int onedimcounter = 0;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                temp.add(onedimcounter++, line);
        }

            System.out.println(temp);
            twodim = temp.toArray(new String[temp.size()][temp.get(0).length()]);
            System.out.println("stage 2 complete");
            System.out.println(twodim);
    }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
            System.out.println("No file found boss.");
    }
        catch(IOException ex){
            System.out.println("IO error.");
        }

  }

}
```

Few more queries,

1) [1st line, 2nd line, ..., nth line] - the comma denotes that the first and second line are separate elements, right?

2) I'm getting an ArrayStoreException and I'm really not 100% sure why - the documentation mentioned something about a casting error, so I'm assuming my arraylist items are still stuck as objects. How do I fix this?

3) Current plan for modification is to list the element index in the final array, modify and reprint, but I've chunked it line by line to preserve the formatting. Need a bit of conformation I'm on the right track here, my idea was to parse the line for doubles, do what I need to do and then try and get the computer to count the number of whitespaces between digits and replace build a string, which then I can just reinsert. Something like a counter with an if statement based off of some boolean looking for white space, then the counter will insert " " when I concatenate the final string.

Cheers.

Comment: How are the values stored? Is it in a plain text format, which is tab delimited (or any other delimited for that matter)?

Comment: This is not a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

First, parse the file to a table of values with associated position-in-file metadata.

Second implement all mutations on that table in terms of atomic duplication/insertion/removal of cells/rows/columns which also update position-in-file.

Third, implement a table serialize operator which takes in the old content so that you can look up the white-space between data lines and between cells within a line, and so you can deduce the number format (number of sig digits) from the old file when serializing changed numeric values.

---

> how do I find and parse the position in file metadata?

To associate position information, keep track of

```
/** Number of line breaks since start of file */
int lineNumber;  
/** Number of chars since start of file */
int charInFile;
/** Number of chars since start of line (if on the zero-th line) or last line break. */
int charInLine;
```

Then with each token, associate the position before the first character, and the position after the last character in the token.

When you parse a complex construct like a table, table row, or table cell, store with it the position before the first token that it spans, and the position after the last token it spans.

---

> what's a table serialize operator? I know of serialization just not that

By *operator*, I just means part of a programming language that allows you to specify a relation between inputs and outputs.  I use it to avoid language-specific jargon like *function*, *method*, or *procedure*.

---

> how do you enter a return key in stack overflow

See "[What is the reason for the top secret two space newline markdown weirdness?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40976/what-is-the-reason-for-the-top-secret-two-space-newline-markdown-weirdness)"

Comment: Question 1, how do I find and parse the position in file metadata?             

Question 2, what's a table serialise operator? I know of serialisation just not that.

Question 3, how do you enter a return key in stack overflow haha

Comment: I think it would help to explain how one would go about doing each of these steps. I feel like there are a lot of terms thrown in here that a "newbie programmer" wouldn't get.

Comment: @MikeSamuel I'll give it a crack, hopefully come back with a comprehensive how I did it post for others.

Comment: @Verlet64, I wrote [this JS parser](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/caja/parser/js/Parser.java) for a project of mine which uses a `TokenQueue` with `FilePosition`s to keep track of position information within a JavaScript code rewriter.